# Network requests are failing - NSURLSession - App Sandbox - Xcode 9

Tags: objective-c, json, nsurlsession, nsmutableurlrequest, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have a simple `GET` request that I am trying to run in my macOS application. However I keep getting the following error:

> A server with the specified hostname could not be found.

The URL I am trying to download JSON data from is:

> https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=safari&q=mercedes

If I test it in my browser or in an online API tester website (such as Hurl.it), the request works fine. A JSON file is then downloaded automatically.

However running the request via my macOS app does not work. Here is my code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=safari&q=mercedes"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", data);
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        
}] resume];
```

Here is the full error log:

> dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
> dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
> dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
> dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed
>
> path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:6 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not
> permitted 2017-10-27 09:58:31.610493+0100 search suggestions
> [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked
> DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)
> TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x600000164080]: 10:-72000 Err(-65563)
> Task <12212C3B-8606-49C2-BD72-AEBD575DB638>.<1> HTTP load failed
> (error code: -1003 [10:-72000])
> Task
> <12212C3B-8606-49C2-BD72-AEBD575DB638>.<1> finished with error - code:
> -1003
>
> Data: (null)
> Response: (null)
> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified
> hostname could not be found." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60400004fa20 {Error
> Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)"
> UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000,
> _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=safari&q=mercedes,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=safari&q=mercedes,
> _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not
> be found.}

What am I doing wrong? It's just a simple `GET` request, I don't understand why the data won't load.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, even though I had set `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `YES`, this is no longer enough to enable network requests.

[image: Allow Arbitrary Loads]

There is a new setting in `Xcode 9` called `App Sandbox` that can stop incoming/outgoing network connections too! I had to turn this setting off and then all network requests started to work.

[image: App Sandbox Setting]

Comment: I just spent two days trying to debug why I couldn't get my WebView's to work.  It was the sandbox setting.  Thanks for this post.

Answer (score 5):

In XCode 11.5 I had to check these two flags

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You have to turn off the "App Sandbox".

Go to:

`xcode Project-> Capabilities -> App SandBox`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLConnection *connection;

NSMutableString *urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:BASE_URL];

[urlString appendFormat:@"%@",apiName]; //apiName —> Webservice Name

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

[request setValue:@"gF!DeEfFrjqaAaD$gH#Mn@w(z" forHTTPHeaderField:@"PC-API-KEY"];  //Optional Parameter pass if required key
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; //if your required Get than  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[parameterDict toJSON]];
[request setTimeoutInterval:45.0];

self.connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (self.connection) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    self.downLoadedData = [NSMutableData data];
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this will solve my problem. It's basically the same code as mine, except it uses the delegate methods to load in the data, rather than a block.

Comment: Also my app is for the ```macOS``` platform, so ```[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];``` is not applicable.